# I need a valve siphon or device to empty a boat that doesnt need a battery or power

Tags: waste-water-treatment, siphon

Maybe something cool actually exists. Something clever. I was actually thinking of an hydraulic ram but im not sure it's a good idea. Another thing i saw was a one-way check valve. Would this work?

Comment: “Doesn’t need a battery *or* power” - it takes energy to move mass, sorry. What inputs *are* available? Human effort?

Comment: How much water & how often, how big is the boat, what type of boat?  Why not solar panels?  Or a wind generator on top of the mast (assuming a sail boat)?

Answer (score 1):

You can buy a mechanical pump that you work by hand for this purpose. It has a cylinder with a piston inside, a suction hose, and a discharge hose. You dip the suction hose into the bilge water, aim the discharge hose overboard, and push the handle on the piston back and forth like a bicycle pump. This is called a *manual bilge pump*.